# Using SQLITE SELECT ... IN statement with string arrays in C# gives empty results with more than one value in array

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have table with columns something like this:

```
table(INT id, serial, data)
```

And I want to create following SELECT command:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE serial IN (list-of-serial)
```

But problem is that when I add more than one value into list-of-serial, I get empty query.

For example:

```
id serial
1  1234
2  5678
3  1234
4  9012
5  1234
6  5678
7  9012

SELECT * FROM table WHERE serial IN ('1234','9012')
```

In this form, it works, but I need to convert it into C# query.

```
string file="my-sqlite-database";
SQLiteConnection database = new SQLiteConnection($@"URI=file:{file}");
database.Open();
SQLiteCommand C = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM table WHERE serial IN (@serials)", database);
C.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serials","('1234','9012')");
C.Prepare();
SQLiteDataReader R = C.ExecuteReader();
While(R.Read()){} // 0 rows
```

What am I doing wrong? I have tried passing string arrays, string with and without quotes, no difference.

Comment: It won't work like this. This will essentially look for a row where the serial is **literally** `('1234','9012')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you inject it directly into the SQL statement, a parameter will only ever be interpreted as a literal value. So it will be looking for a single string matching `('1234','9012')`. And injection is a bad idea, which you should generally avoid.

Unfortunately, SQLite does not support Table-Valued parameters. So you need to use multiple parameters here:

```cs
string file = "my-sqlite-database";
var parms = new string[]{"1234", "9012"};
using (SQLiteConnection database = new SQLiteConnection($@"URI=file:{file}"))
using (SQLiteCommand C = new SQLiteCommand("", database))
{
    C.Parameters.AddRange(parms.Select((p, ind) => new SqliteParameter("@p" + ind, p)));
    C.CommandText = $@"
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE serial IN ({string.Join(",", parms.Select((p, ind) => "@p" + ind))})
";
    database.Open();
    C.Prepare();
    using (SQLiteDataReader R = C.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(R.Read())
        { //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Dapper can do the above natively, so you may want to look at that.

Note also correct use of `using` blocks to dispose.

Comment: Thanks, it works! And is probably most safe way to pass variables.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, I might be wrong.
I have never used C# but I feel like what is happening might be that `"('1234','9012')"` is counted as a string.
Did you try making an array and passing the array instead?

Comment: Yes, it does not work like this.